# Xamarin Forms Grouping List View Not Displaying Iterating Row

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView that has a 'sub' list within it that needs to be displayed.

XAML:

```
  <ListView Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceDatesFinalCollectionOutput}" IsGroupingEnabled="True" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding ServicesHeader.ServiceType}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding ServicesHeader.ServiceType}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Class:

```
private ObservableCollection<ServiceDatesModel.ServiceDatesCombined> _ServiceDatesFinalCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<ServiceDatesModel.ServiceDatesCombined> ServiceDatesFinalCollectionOutput
        {
            get { return _ServiceDatesFinalCollection; }

        }


    public class ServiceDatesCombined
        {
            public Service ServicesHeader { get; set; }

            public List<Servicedate> ServicesDetails { get; set; }

        }


  public class Servicedate
        {
            public string desc { get; set; }
            public object endDate { get; set; }
            public string startDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime startDateNonString { get; set; }
            public string descDetail { get; set; }
        }
```

Whenever I try to view - I only see the first ServicesHeader.ServiceType displaying but not the remaining. Most importantly, I do not see the TextCell content.

Any pointers appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: please read the docs on how to format your data for grouping - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix the model, and also the view. The group model class should be `IEnumerable`. The `ListView.ItemTemplate` binding context will be `Servicedate` class (I guess it's the details class).

Then to make it work, the class `ServiceDatesCombined` should be a `IEnumeable`.

```
...
public class ServiceDatesCombined : IEnumerable
{
    public Service ServicesHeader { get; set; }

    public List<Servicedate> ServicesDetails { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ServicesDetails?.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
...
```

There are a little adjust for XAML code.

```
...
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceDatesFinalCollectionOutput}"
              IsGroupingEnabled="True" 
              GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding ServicesHeader.ServiceType}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding desc}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
...
```

I recommend you to read the [ListView Appearance documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping)